Hegel vs Kant - meaning of "transcendent"

For Kant, the "transcendent", is that which lies beyond what our
faculty of knowledge can legitimately know. Hegel's counter-argument
to Kant was that to know a boundary is also to be aware of what it
bounds and as such what lies beyond it – in other words, to have
already transcended it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_(philosophy)

If Hegel means that humans can have an idea about everything, never mind they could be wrong.
But Kant. What exactly is this boundary, according to Kant, where we cannot have knowledge?

For Kant, the boundary where we cannot have knowledge is fundamentally tied to the distinction between phenomena (the objects as we experience them) and noumena (things-in-themselves, or things as they are independent of our perception). Kant argues that human knowledge is limited to what is phenomenal, that is, to the way things appear to us through the structures of our cognition and affection...

Kant examines the conditions of the possibility of knowledge. For Kant, the limit is the subject; for him, the subject can never emerge from itself, so the senses are between the world and things in themselves. Hegel removes this separation in order to derive his pantheism with development; Kant was a purely immanent philosopher (with the exception of his regulative ideas).

"the subject can never emerge from itself" - what does this statement mean, and where does Kant make a similar claim?

@Jo For Kant, the senses lie between things in themselves and the subject, so the subject cannot perceive things as they really are. Kant thus refuted naive realism. Hegel, on the other hand, was a realist who assumed that things are what they appear to be.

@tenebris While we could argue about most of your points being correct, the last sentence in that comment clearly is problematic since Hegel argued about the illusion of object-subject dichotomy since he wrote the Phenomenology, hence it is at least oversimplified to say that "things are what they appear to be".

@Klöcking For Kant, things in themselves are never accessible; the apple would be real, but cannot be recognized as what it appears to be. For Schopenhauer, the will to live is what Kant sees as the unknowable thing in itself. Hegel assumes a dialectical process, but things in the world are assumed to be real. I can also provide a quote on this. But clearly for Hegel, an apple is an apple, even though the real things in the world are subjected to the dialectical process, just as for Schopenhauer, the will to live is subjected to evolution.

"the subject can never emerge from itself" - What does it mean in plain English?

To understand Kant well, you have to at least read the introduction and understand what the court of pure reason is. Unfortunately, I only know Kant in German and don't know which translation I can recommend here. Kant tries to examine the cognitive apparatus in its entirety, so he starts from human thought, not empirical reality.

@tenebris For Hegel, things in the world are aspects of the world spirit experiencing itself through individual instances of itself. Even if they are real, that's hardly "what they appear to be".

I have already mentioned that there is a dialectical process. What then is a quark according to Hegel? Or a photon? It is what it appears to be. Kant, on the other hand, says that it is not accessible to the subject.

Try to explain quantum physics using Hegel, then I think it will become clear what the sentence above means.

Philosophy should not be advanced mathematics, comprehensible to a few. If there is a meaning, it should be possible to describe it in plain words.

For example, the simulation hypothesis describes another level of reality where someone or something controls the laws of nature. Is it what Kant meant?

@Matrix I want to be honest, you won't understand Kant without reading him. I will try to improve the answer so that it is roughly understandable, but you can only really understand Kant if you read him. Hegel is just misleading because he postulates pure realism and that can be quickly demonstrated in physics, you don't need much mathematics for that.

@tenebris - You intrigued me. I could say: "You cannot understand Tchaikovsky until you have listened to his symphony #5 five times :)" But a philosopher is not a poet.

@Matrix With an IQ of over 130, it took me 2 years to read his main work and I spent the whole day reading it. I don't want to demotivate you, but I do want to point out that it is very difficult and you will always make mistakes in the beginning. Weizsäcker also say this. There are many simple philosophers (Foucault, Seneca, Marcus Aurelius, etc.). Unfortunately, Kant is not one of them. :)
